# Remove a port to the external bridge with openvswitch

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I was setting up a openstack configuration using this document:
http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/openstack-install-guide-apt-juno.pdf
and got to page 72 where it says to do this:

```
# ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex INTERFACE_NAME
```

but i put the wrong INTERFACE_NAME, and now i have to correct that mistake (it is a real interface, but the wrong one, i was supposed to put another one in there).

But i have trouble undoing that.

I tried:

```
# ovs-vsctl del-port br-ex INTERFACE_NAME
```

but it tells me that /etc/openvswitch/conf.db (or something like that) is read-only

i then tried

```
# ovs-vsctl del-br br-ex
```

Bu then it says that you cant just delete a port, you need to delete the entire bridge (or something like that). Which is wierd to me, i thought that that command would delete the bridge...

So does anyone know the correct way to delete the port i mistakenly made?

EDIT:  And i tried all that as root.

EDIT2:  I just tried on a practice machine do the same thing, make the same error and then fix it with:

```
# ovs-vsctl del-port br-ex INTERFACE_NAME
```

and it worked, no read-only nonesense, so i really dont get it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @M36M4N cro did you find a solution?

Comment: @Pheonix7 this was quite some time ago but i think i did, see Edit2. Maybe it was a bug, i think that i tried setting up the whole machine from the start